# How to send WebDAV Headers with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, webdav, owncloud

I'm trying to talk to an Owncloud server (Sabre/webDAV) using ruby 2.0. I have a Curl example for getting a file listing which requires passing info in the HTTP headers. How can I pass this header info from Ruby? The [net_dav docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/devrandom/net_dav/Net/DAV#headers-instance_method) seem to show this is an available method but the ruby error seems to suggest otherwise:

**EDIT**: fixed syntax error `headers =` to `headers()`

`undefined method headers= for #<Net::DAV:0x00000001276d10> (NoMethodError)`

Curl command:

```
# curl -s -X PROPFIND -H "Depth: 100" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u ${username}:${passwd} https://myserver.net/remote.php/webdav | egrep href
```

ruby code:

```
    # get list of files
    url = "https://myserver.net"
    path = "/remote.php/webdav/"

    dav = Net::DAV.new(url, :curl => false)
    dav.verify_server = true
    dav.credentials(user, pass)
    dav.headers ("Depth: 100")  # << something wrong ?

    # get list of files
    path = "/remote.php/webdav/"
    options = ''
    props = dav.propfind(path, options)
```

Comment: Depth: 100 is not a thing. It can only be `0`, `1` or `infinity`

Comment: Are you sure? Varying the depth from 0-3 seems to give me the logical levels of directory structure. `inifinity` is indeed what I want though. thanks.

Comment: If the server you are interacting with supports `Depth: 3`, then that server is also implementing a non-standard feature. Reference: I've done a _lot_ of webdav work and you can find it in the specs too ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found out the v0.5 Gem on rubygems.org is far behind the v0.5 code on the net_dav github page. [This comment](https://github.com/devrandom/net_dav/issues/33) shows how to get the updated Gem that works.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you linked says to use `dav.headers()`, you're using `dav.headers =`. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Good catch. The code I pasted was after trying it in parenthesis (I'm new to ruby :/). Fixed, but still get the `NoMethodError` error